# Amplify @model @auth not adding owner from onCreate

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql

I have the following attached to a table in my schema:

@model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create, delete, update] }])

When I create a new record using the gui in amplify console api, an owner is added to the record. But when my code creates a new record, the owner is null.

I am using the graphql query generated by amplify codegen. Am I missing a step that automatically attaches an owner to a new record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *should* just work.

If you go look at your AppSync API's request mapping template for the mutation that you're using to create a new record, you should see a section like this in the VTL that Amplify generated for you:

```
## [Start] Owner Authorization Checks **
  #set( $isOwnerAuthorized = false )
  ## Authorization rule: { allow: owner, ownerField: "owner", identityClaim: "cognito:username" } **
  #set( $allowedOwners0 = $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.input.owner, null) )
  #set( $identityValue = $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.identity.claims.get("username"), $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.identity.claims.get("cognito:username"), "___xamznone____")) )
  #if( $util.isList($allowedOwners0) )
    #foreach( $allowedOwner in $allowedOwners0 )
      #if( $allowedOwner == $identityValue )
        #set( $isOwnerAuthorized = true )
      #end
    #end
  #end
  #if( $util.isString($allowedOwners0) )
    #if( $allowedOwners0 == $identityValue )
      #set( $isOwnerAuthorized = true )
    #end
  #end
  #if( $util.isNull($allowedOwners0) && (! $ctx.args.input.containsKey("owner")) )
    $util.qr($ctx.args.input.put("owner", $identityValue))
    #set( $isOwnerAuthorized = true )
  #end
  ## [End] Owner Authorization Checks **
```

Look at the line toward the bottom: `$util.qr($ctx.args.input.put("owner", $identityValue))` -- this is what's setting the `owner` property, assuming the input didn't already contain an `owner` property.

So, here are the reasons I can think of for why mutations issued from your code might not be ending up with owner:

- Are you sure you're logged in to your app and that you're submitting your GraphQL mutation using the AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS authorization mode? If you're authorizing the request via, say IAM, you won't have an owner come through the identity claims.
- Are you passing a blank value in for `owner` in the input you're sending? This would prevent it from being assigned to the cognito username in the mapping template.

Comment: A few months later and the problem seemed to just fix itself. But thanks for the answer, I appreciate it!

Comment: I've got a similar problem... The only thing I can think of that I've done wrong is setup just for API Auth to start with... but I'm not sure it should be manual to add Cognito Auth in this part... Amplify seems to be happy adding most everything else back it...
I've been using Amplify since 2019 and I often find it can be easier just to create a new project and shift your JS code over... so I'll give that a try...
If I don't report back flag me down and I'll give anyone interested an update.

Comment: re: previous comment. Recreating the project a new seems to have solved this. One thing I've noticed is that the old one did not have a Function `<Model_Name>OwnerDataResolverFn` (the one that was not functional.)
This Function is found in the same place as the Function Gabe refers to. That is, in the APIs functions sub-menu category in the AWS console.

The Function Gabe refers to has a name like: Mutationcreate<Model_Name>auth0Function
For this one:
My broken one was 22 lines.
My working one was 47 lines.

Hope this helps anyone else.

Comment: Doesn't creating a new project mean you have to create new environements? What if you have a production environment? How would you retain the data?